# How to compare column elements to the column's mode?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find the probability that a value in a column is equal to the columns mean. I have tried the following:

```
count = 0
for column_name, column_data in creoles[creoles.columns[2:]].iteritems():
    mode = creoles[column_name].mode()
    data = creoles[column_name].tolist()
    for i in data:
        for j in mode:
            if i == j:
                count += 1
    baseline = round(count / len(data), 3)
    
    
    count = 0
```

but I recieve the following Error:
`A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`

I am not sure if that applies to my specific situation, or if it does how I would go about doing that. I've looked online for a while and couldn't find a solution. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As the mean is just one favorable outcome, you could just divide the favorable outcome for all the possibilites, such as:

```
prob_eq_mean = 1/df['column'].count()
```

Comment: What does the 1 represent here?

Comment: The probability of something happening is: number of favorable outcomes divided by all possible outcomes. You only have one favorable outcome that is any value in your column being equal to the mean.

Comment: Despite what intuition might say, without any assumption over the distribution of the population, the more values you have in that column, less probable is that any of them is equal to the mean.